# My drupal 7 is very slow even if I did many improvements

Tags: performance, commerce

I'm builind a Drupal 7 web site using commerce kickstart 2 distribution, the site became very slow, mainly the admin pages.
I read many answers here in stackexchange, and some articles talk about drupal performance, so I did the following steps :

- disabling some modules :update manager,Internationalization,Localization update,database logging.
- setting cron running to: never
- enabling cache pages for anonymous users and enabling cache block
- enbaling: Aggregate and compress CSS files and aggregate JavaScript files.
- adding this line to settings.php: ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

After one day my site back to work normaly, but today it's back slow as first time.

I'm using a **shared hosting**, so I went so Cpanel>select your php version> I enabled the following extension : apc,memeache,memecached.
 I also set memory_limit to 512 (I'm not sure if this settings requires a server restart).
Even If all this steps, thi site still very slow and I don't know what I can do.

Comment: apc and opcache should probably not be turned on at the same time. For PHP < 5.5, use APC. For PHP >= 5.5, use the build in cache instead. xdebug is _NOT_ a performance improvement, it's a debugging tool that could cause severe slowdowns.
Other than that the question is to broad, you'll need to work out why it's slow, we can't do that for you as there could be a million reasons.

Comment: Letharion, my PHP version is 5.3, myquestion is about is what I should do else disbaling modules? and what I did is help or make site more slow? and if my hosting cause the problem so can request a feature from the hosting support? I hope it's a bit clear, I can edit and improve my question

Comment: @Letharion Opcache + APC user cache is quite common - not both opcaches at the same time though. The problem we've got, murad, is that it's almost impossible to guess what might be wrong/slow with your site from here. It really requires someone who knows what they're doing to profile the site and make decisions from there. People can make broad guesses as to how things might be improved, but without access to the bare metal it's almost impossible to give a reliable response

Comment: @Clive, I guess, though for performance reasons, the basic thing to do is getting an opcode cache working, and then you have no use of both of them, correct?

Comment: @murad Get a better host that doesn't offer 5.3. 5.3 isn't supported anymore, and you will gain significant performance improvements simply by running a recent version of PHP.

Comment: @Clive you mean I should disable one of APC and and Opcache and keep just one? I tried this tool http://www.macronsoftware.com/drupal-performance-analyzer it show me that some js and css aren't agregated.

Comment: @Letharion so I should change it to 5.5 right?

Comment: @Letharion Sort of - opcache is for compiling/caching results of predictable code; APC user cache (not opcache) is a normal cache mechanism, like you'd use memcache or redis for example. They're not mutually exclusive, it would be perfectly reasonable to have both enabled. But you certainly wouldn't want to use APC opcache and Zend opcache at the same time, that would be redundant

Comment: @murad if you have to ask, you probably shouldn't be the one in charge of implementing it :) This isn't an area to get into if you don't know exactly what you're doing, bad things can happen if you configure things anything other than just right

Comment: @Clive I knew, I don't have a choice, my site become very slow, I read that I have to enable apc, opcache and memecache, I asked If I did it wrong, that's all. Hope you understand me.

Comment: I do understand, I was in the same position once upon a time - unfortunately, there isn't an answer that anyone here can give you. Your experience using opcaches/caches in general will depend on many, many things - server resources, traffic, what modules you're using and how well optimised they are, and so on. It isn't a matter of "enable these things and your site will magically be quicker". I mean, that may happen, but it's far more likely that you'll need to tweak the settings within the context of your website/server

Comment: Actually, if you've enabled memcache, but don't run a memcache server, that could potentially break caching entirely, if the memcache module takes over caching and then has nowhere to write it's cached values. So make sure you understand what's going on there. :)

Comment: Yep, what @Letharion said is pretty much my exact point - unless you know what you're doing, don't do it :)

Comment: @Letharion Well I changed the PHP version to 5.5 and I disabled memecache and memecached, I didn't find APC in 5.5 extensions just (APCU), I kept Opcache.

Comment: @Letharion after disabling a little custom module,moving to 5.5 PHP Version, running cron,APCU,memecache and memecached are disabled, the site work normaly now, I hope it still work like that even if I don't know the cause :).

Comment: you can disable UI modules on production which will give you more Improvement, to do that you can use  Administration menu -> Disable development modules or  manually [371287].(https://www.drupal.org/node/371287#comment-1247472)